# Hiding a java applet with jquery? Possible?

Tags: jquery, applet

I'm struggling to find a way to hide a java applet () using jquery.

I have a link that opens up a simple ajax fancybox (http://fancybox.net) problem is that it always appears 'behind' the actual java applet.

Is there a way to 'hide' the applet or even unload it? I can reload it after closing the fancybox (basically asking for user confirmation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove it's DOM object, or set it's CSS property to hidden.

```
jQuery("#applet").remove();
```

or

```
jQuery("#applet").hide();
```

You can also [kill the applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267033/kill-java-applet-via-javascript):

```
 <script>
 document.MyApplet.killApplet();
 </script>

 public void killApplet() 
 {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() 
   {

        public Void run() {
            // kill the JVM
            System.exit(0);
            return null;
        }
    });
 }
```

However, this stops the applet, and throws JS errors in IE6

You can also set the applets size to (1,1), and set it back when you're finished.

```
jQuery("#applet").height(1).width(1);
```

Comment: Ok, .hide() works. But when I put 'show' it doesn't show it back

Comment: i have : <applet id="myapplet"> and then $("#myapplet").hide() works, but $("#myapplet").show() doesn't.

Comment: Flash has this problem too, you set the Window Mode to transparent for it. Don't know if you can do this with Java Applets or not.

Comment: mmmh ... is there a way to tell jquery to 'change' the applet src ? that could solve the problem

Comment: jQuery("#applet").attr("src", "null");

Comment: mmh seems a bug of fancy box : 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a#ajax").fancybox({
  'onStart':  function() {  alert ('opened');},
  'onClosed':  function() { alert ('closed'); }
 });
});

onclosed is never displayed.

Comment: So trigger it yourself :) jQuery("fancybox").trigger("closed");

Comment: i'm really new to jquery; what is the 'trigger' supposed to do ? how to use it ?

Comment: trigger triggers an event handler. You can use it to cause custom events. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/  For example, if I did jQuery("#button").tigger("click") it would fire the click event of the button.

Comment: ok I see but i need to do some action when user clicks on the close button of fancybox; onClosed function doesn't seem to work (http://fancybox.net/api)

Answer (score 5):

What I do is $('applet').addClass('hide');

```
.hide {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}
```

Do $('applet').removeClass('hide'); when you want it back.

All other options will force restarting your applet.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var save=$('#applet').clone();
$('#applet').html('');
```

and when You need it back

```
$('#applet').html(save.html());
save=null; //to free this bit of memory
```

not tested, but I expect it to work ;)