# Killing applet through javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have created an applet which has a necessity to execute the following code:

### Code

```
public class Example extends JApplet {
private ServerSocket ss ;
private Socket socket;
private boolean closed;

@Override
public void init(){
    try {
        new Example().initialize();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
    }
}
public void closed(){
    System.out.println("Inside close");
    this.closed=true;
  }
public void initialize() throws IOException{
    ss =new ServerSocket(5002);
    while(!closed){
    System.out.println("Waiting to accept request");
    socket = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Request accepted");
    } 
}}
```

### HTML

Fragment of HTML file to execute applet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >  
 function closeCall(){  
 document.app.closed();  
 }  
 </script>  
   <body>  
<applet id="app" code="example.Example" archive="Example.jar" height="300" width="300">    
   </applet>  
   <input type="button" value="go" onClick="closeCall()" />
```

Problem: On clicking <kbd>Go</kbd> my browser stops responding and there is no error in javascript code as well. Is there any way to call the `document.app.closed();`  method?

Comment: If by 'close' you mean you want it to disappear from the page, give it an ID, and use the JS to set the 'visibility' of that ID to 'none' (check the stuff in inverted commas in a CSS reference - I have not had my coffee yet).  Do NOT try to end the VM!

Comment: I only just noticed the [tag:sockets] tag.  Do you mean close the ***socket?***

Comment: As an aside, a standard applet does not have a `close()` method.  What exactly does yours do?  What output is in the Java Console and JavaScript error reporting component?  Do you have an URL where we can see the applet live?

Comment: @AndrewThompson No there is not hiding trouble and neither I want to close socket.I want to call the close method in java from javascript and when I call it my browser stops responding.And I am sorry I dont have an URL where you can see the applet live.

Comment: `while(true){` should probably read `while(!closed){`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Do you see `Inside close` in the Java Console?

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry i forgot to edit that.And yes I have checked in java console, `Inside close` is not printed.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console report?  In FF it might be under Tools|Web Developer|Error Console.  Where is the (copy/pasted) SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have edited the question again.And there is no javscript error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was only after turning that code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)<sup>1</sup> that the many problems became clear:

- This code failed for me without any sign of JS.  That indicates to me that this has ***nothing*** to do with JS!
- The instance of `Example` on which `initialize()` was called was not the same as that which was the applet!  It did not matter if the UI ever detected the JS, it would not have stopped the running instance.
- The `accept()` was blocking the EDT.
- Setting `closed` to `true` was not about to have an effect until after the next client connected and the code looped around to check the value of the `closed` attribute again.  I achieved it by calling `ss.close()` (which makes the `closed` attribute redundant BTW - but I left it in).

#### BTW

1. Please consider posting an SSCCE in future.

### Code

Try this version:

```
// <applet code='Example' width=400 height=100></applet>
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Example extends JApplet {
    private ServerSocket ss ;
    private Socket socket;
    private boolean closed;

    @Override
    public void init(){
        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop!");
        stop.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                closed();
            }
        });
        add( stop );
        validate();

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    initialize();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }

    public void closed() {
        System.out.println("Inside close");
        closed=true;
        try {
            ss.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        ss =new ServerSocket(5002);
        while(!closed){
            System.out.println("Waiting to accept request");
            socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Request accepted");
        }
    }
}
```

### Run

I have added a button to this version so that you can check it works as expected **without JavaScript** (which you should have checked with your own code before tossing JS into the mix).  The single line comment at the top of the source is used by AppletVewer to put the code on-screen.  Use it like this:

```
prompt> appletviewer Example.java
```

### Typical Output

```
Waiting to accept request
Inside close
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at Example.initialize(Example.java:51)
    at Example$2.run(Example.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Tool completed successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the applet security sandbox allows you to invoke a `System#exit()`. Even when it did, it would be bad for user experience as the enduser wouldn't be able to run it again without reopening the page in browser.

Rather let that `while` intercept on a `boolean` instance variable which you toggle in the `close()` method. E.g.

```
private boolean closed;

public void initialize() {
    while (!closed) {
        // ...
    }
}

public void close() {
    this.closed = true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code as well but I guess socket = ss.accept(); line stops me to close or even to exit.Is there any solution?

Comment: Just set a timeout on socket connection and/or call `close()` on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

try this from [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/dhqX7SEt) and [kill-java-applet-via-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267033/kill-java-applet-via-javascript)

```
<script>
 document.MyApplet.killApplet();
 </script>


 public void killApplet()
 {
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
   {

        public Void run() {
            // kill the JVM
            System.exit(0);
            return null;
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Killing the JVM is utterly irresponsible.  I'd be surprised if it worked in any current VM.